# Getting an intermittent script-thrown exception error when using compile + matcher with a regex

Tags: apex, callout, regular-expressions

We have an old method that checks a string for an email format to determine what we'll append to it to make it a Salesforce username on user creation (subsequent step). This is called in a new method that is exposed for HTTP callouts.

However, the code for the old method (see below) has started to fail intermittently on the *matcher* step.

The stack trace returns '(System Code)', so does this mean it's something happening on Salesforce's end that fails and requires a case to be raised with SF? Or could it be there's something wrong with the regex?

(System Code)
Class.CIM_Utility.appendUsernameSuffix: line 108, column 1

```
public static string appendUsernameSuffix(string username){
    // Check if username is in email format
    // if in email format + USERNAME_SUFFIX
    // if not in email format + USERNAME_SUFFIX_EMAIL

String emailRegex = '^[a-zA-Z0-9._|\\\'\\\\%#~`=?&/$^*!}{+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$';
Pattern MyPattern = Pattern.compile(emailRegex);
Matcher MyMatcher = MyPattern.matcher(username); // line 108
if (MyMatcher.matches()){
    username += UtilityClass.USERNAME_SUFFIX;
}
else{
    username += UtilityClass.USERNAME_SUFFIX_EMAIL;
}
```

Comment: The relevant, more interesting exception should appear just in front of that "(System Code)" output in the stack trace. Could you have a second look at the logs? One possible explanation: username was null. In that case you'd get something like "System.NullPointerException: Script-thrown exception ... (System Code) ...".